# Discord.js music bot does not respond to first music request

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, discord, discord.js, youtube-data-api

I've been coding an all purpose bot recently for my discord server, and have been running into some problems with music requests. there is currently no queue system, and i'm not sure if I plan to implement one, so at the moment, if a song is playing and a new one is requested, the current one is skipped and the new one starts playing. my problem however is that when a song is playing and a new one is requested, it just plays the last requested song, AKA the current one. this essentially means that the songs are always one request behind. my code for the music part is as follows

```
var channel;
var dispatcher;
var contentID;
var playing = false;
var queue = [] bot.on("message", message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(musicPrefix.length).split(" ");
    //GOOGLE API AREA!

    channel = message.member.voice.channel
    if (!message.guild && args[0] === "play") return message.reply('Please send music requests in a Sleepybot© supported server!');
    switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case ("play"):
            google.youtube("v3").search.list({
                    key: youtubeToken,
                    part: "snippet",
                    q: message.content.slice(6),
                    maxResults: 1,
            }).then((response) => {
                const { data } = response data.items.forEach((item) => {
                    console.log(item.id.videoId);
                    contentID = item.id.videoId;
                });
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err)); //if (message.member.voice.channel) {

            if (!channel) {
                message.reply("you must be in a voice channel to play music!");
                return;
            } else if (!args[1]) return message.reply("please specify a song title or link");

            channel.join().then(connection => {
                var sound = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + contentID; // const stream = ytdl(sound, { filter: 'audioonly' })
                //  if(playing===false){
                const stream = ytdl(sound, { filter: 'audioonly' });
                dispatcher = connection.play(stream); 
                console.log('playing something');
                playing = true;
                return;
            });
            break;
        case ("disconnect"):
            message.reply("disconnecting...") dispatcher.end();
            if (!channel) {
                message.reply("there was an error leaving the channel");
            } else {
                channel.leave() message.reply("disconnected");
            }
            playing = false; //you may not just "leave all channels" you need to leave a specific one, so make sure you're leaving the one it's in
            break;
        case ("pause"):
            dispatcher.pause() message.reply("Paused"); console.log("paused");
            break;
        case ("resume"):
            dispatcher.resume() message.reply("resumed!"); console.log("resumed");
            break;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As you may have noticed, I spent 15 minutes editting your code to make it readable... Please take into consideration that others need to be able to read the code to fix problems. Mis-indented, jumbled-up code will rarely be reviewed by anyone. 
I also think I know what the problem is, now that I can read it. I will post an answer soon.

Comment: There are tools online to "beautify" code btw.. Just lookup javascript beautifier online. (Plus, I read the edit someone made to your post to remove the intro saying that you already knew that the code was messy, sorry if it came across as harsh as I thought you just threw out the code for people to fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using promises in javascript, anything that depends on the result of a promise needs to be within the lambda function provided to `.then()`. Example

```
promise.then((response) => {
  // after the promise calls the lambda function provided
});
// code runs immediately right after the promise is **created**, not when done running
```

In your situation, you are running code **outside** of the lambda. This means it will run that "outside" code instantly after creating the promise, whether or not it called `.then()`... To fix this: move the part that plays the audio

```
if (!channel) {
    //.........
channel.join().then(connection => {
    //........
    return;
});
```

into here

```
google.youtube("v3").search.list({
        key: youtubeToken,
        part: "snippet",
        q: message.content.slice(6),
        maxResults: 1,
}).then((response) => { // START OF LAMBDA FUNCTION
    const { data } = response data.items.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item.id.videoId);
        contentID = item.id.videoId;
    });
    // ----------------
    // INSERT CODE HERE
    // ----------------
    // END OF LAMBDA FUNCTION
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Hopefully that fixes your problem. :)

Comment: thank you so much! this did the trick. I'll make sure I make my code more organized and readable in the future!

Comment: @Sleepybear1x you should probably mark it as solved then ^^